# Polynomial operations in matlab

Tags: matlab, polynomials

I have three polynomials a(x), b(x) and p(x) over Galois field GF(2^n), and I would like to compute a(x)*b(x) % p(x). Can Matlab compute this expression? So far, I have found this, but it doesn't consider the p(x):

```
m=n;
a=[1 0 0 0 1 2] % just a example of numbers, the same type arrays for b and p as well
c = gfconv(a,b,m)
```

It is what I have found after days of searching, but I cannot find anywhere the formula for the type of equation I have.

Comment: Please clarify. What you want to do is unclear.

Comment: Explain what you mean by `a(x)*b(x) % p(x) in GF(2^n)` and what you're trying to solve.

Comment: e.g. A(x)=x^4+3x^2+1, B(x)=x^7+1,P(x)=x^4+3x^2 (totally random equations,it is not the point). A(x)*B(x)modP(x)=?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for remd in this expression (http://nl.mathworks.com/help/comm/galois-fields-of-odd-characteristic.html).

```
a = gf([1 0 0 0 1 2],n); %your example
b = gf([1 1],n); %just example
p = gf([1 0],n); % just example

[quot,remd] = deconv(conv(a,b),p);
```

Note that functions gfconv and gfdeconv exist, but Matlab recommends to use standard conv and deconv over 2^n field.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is what I was looking for! However I get a mistake (mine)                                                  Error using gfconv
The field parameter must be a positive prime integer.( p=[1 1 0 0 1]). Could you please explain me why it is like this? Thank you!

Comment: Apologies, just realized that gf functions are not for 2^n. I've adjusted my answer, but cannot test it (have no access to Comm TB on my current system). Let me know if that works

Comment: you just have saved me many hours searching! it works at last! thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome and good luck :). Would you mind accepting my answer that your question does not appear in the unanswered list (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?